# Are 7nm or 10nm transistors reality or is it just a marketing strategy by processor manufacturers?

Tags: transistors, microprocessor, chip-design, semiconductor-process-technology

Now a days chip manufacturers, like Qualcomm, claim that they have built a 7nm chip. Is 7nm really the size of transistor or is it just a marketing strategy? If 7nm is just for marketing and not the size of transistor, then what exactly 7nm is?

Comment: I removed the tags "microchip" and "intel" because your question doesn't ask anything about these companies.

Comment: It's for either gate width or length -- it used to be the smallest feature that you could lay down on the chip, back when the process was limited by the lithography and not physics.  Now it's the smallest transistor that you (well, they) can actually make work.  The actual area of a transistor that you can make is bigger than the published length squared -- and like circuit board layout, you cannot pack transistors that tightly in a real design anyway.

Comment: What advantage do they gain by claiming something that they do not deliver?  Samsung have a 5nm process.  The proof is in the devices these technologies make.

Answer (score 2):

Node size is basically a technology standard for equipment makers, in order to align capabilities (i.e. generations) of manufacturing tooling and their requirements which represent several hundred discrete devices in the wafer processing pipeline generally under the **SEMI** standards organization but the major players (i.e. Intel) have their own standards groups .

What they try to do above else  establish is process consistency (accuracy) , in addition to precision . As you can imagine small node size designs require every precise equipment but are also much more sensitive to variations in process so need more accuracy (repeatable real world value)  as well.  Even if you can make one transistor work you need them all to work to sell a product.

Since a single process step involves many pieces of equipment, they all need to evolve in lock step to support the modern process concepts. Exotic processes may also require exotic materials and much more toxic gasses not well accommodated in current infrastructure, but integral to support the smaller node processes and that is part of the node standard as well.

The process engineers work black magic and they have other meaningful measures of minimum transistor size and density given equipment of a certain category and their own specifications that then get passed to the designers as capabilities of the Fab.

In other words,  On the backend a 7nm tool is magnitudes more consistent than the 100nm, to achieve some product design goal, the 7nm marker is the equipment standard needed to hit that node size, something that has a different meaning to everyone in the supply and design chain for process equipment.

Comment: Sometimes of course, mfgers make up things as marketing assuming there is real meaning behind it, there is such a thing as 7nm node, but what Qualcomm is advertising may not be that , they are fabless company so one can easily research the capabilities of contract fabs today to determine what the real meaning of their claim might be .

Comment: It means they are building it on the lines the fab calls "7 nm". And the fab calls them "7 nm" because they use mask printing equipment, lithography equipment, inspection equipment, etc., that those vendors sold to them as "7 nm". Which gets back to exactly what your answer says: it's a consensus marketing term used across the industry to name a generation of equipment meant to work together.